# Ошибка: NameError: name 'move_shoot' is not defined

Tags: python, алгоритм

```
#задаю движение\\
MOVE_Q=10
def ship_move(press):
    if press.keysym=='Left':
        c.move(ship,-MOVE_Q,0)
        c.move(dom,-MOVE_Q,0)
        c.move(radd,-MOVE_Q,0)
        c.move(flame,-MOVE_Q,0)
    elif press.keysym=='Right':
        c.move(ship,MOVE_Q,0)
        c.move(dom,MOVE_Q,0)
        c.move(radd,MOVE_Q,0)
        c.move(flame,MOVE_Q,0)
    elif press.keysym=='Up':
        move_shoot()
c.bind_all('<Key>',ship_move)
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос полный текст ошибки и покажите тот код, в котором она возникает.

Comment: В вашем примере кода вообще отсутствует идентификатор ```make_shoot```, а все телепаты в отпуске.

Comment: Извините, move_shoot

Comment: Что непонятно в тексте ошибки?

Comment: я не могу понять, что ему не нравится в функции

Comment: sossossossossos

Comment: В тексте ошибки написано, в чем проблема.

Comment: а как решить эту проблему

Comment: я понимаю, что функция не определена, но как это исправить

Comment: Видимо придётся таки определять)

Comment: спасибо, господа, за помощь, очень помогли